# find $\lim \sup x_n$ and $\lim \inf x_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$x_n = \frac {(n-1)(-1)^n}{n}$, find $\lim \sup x_n$ and $\lim \inf x_n$.

Let $a_n = \sup\{x_k : k\ge n\}$ and $b_n = \inf\{x_k : k\ge n\}$.

$a_n = \sup \{\frac {n-1}{n}, \frac {-n}{n+1}, \frac {n+1}{n+2}, \frac {-(n+2)}{n+3}, ...\}$ when $n=even$.

$a_n = \sup \{\frac {-(n-1)}{n}, \frac {n}{n+1}, \frac {-(n+1)}{n+2}, \frac {n+2}{n+3}, ...\}$ when $n=odd$

In both cases, $a_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac {n+k}{n+k+1} = 1$. (*)

Similarly, I found $b_n = -1$.

Therefore, since $\lim \sup x_n= \lim a_n$ and  $\lim \inf x_n = \lim b_n$, $\lim \sup x_n = 1$ and $\lim \inf x_n = -1$ .

Could you check this proof is okay? Is (*) correct?

Comment: Yes, (*) is correct and the proof is OK.

Comment: It is true that $a_n=1$ for every $n.$ Your conclusions are right. But if I were a beginner I would want to know how you can tell that $a_n=1.$

Comment: If the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded then $\lim \sup x_n$  is the largest limit of a convergent sub-sequence and $\lim\inf x_n$ is the smallest. In your Q the positive terms converge to $1$ and the non-positive terms converge to $-1$ so $\pm1$ are the $ only$ limits of sub-sequences.